# exporting sql with special characters output to pipe delimited file

Tags: python, database, oracle

I want to export sql query output to a pipe delimited file using Python. One of the columns of the sql contains special characters. I am able to export the file perfectly but when I open the output file in notepad or excel, certain special characters of the columns are getting converted as pipes '|' and it is throwing my number of columns.

Here's the code:

```
cursor_1 = db_connect.cursor()

sql_query = """select a,b,c from example"""

filename = folder_path+"/abc_{}.txt".format(today)
outputFile = open(filename,'wb') # 'wb'
output = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter='|') 
cursor_1.execute(sql_query)
```

example of value in column "b" of table "example":
R123456 ê´‘ê³ (íŒŒì›Œí´ë¦­) ì±„ë„ ê´€ë¦¬ ë‹´ë‹¹

when I open the file with excel or txt file, few values of the above text gets converted to pipe '|'

Than you for your help !!

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: it is Oracle. forgot to mention.. Thanks!!

Comment: I doubt you will have an answer using an anonymous account.

Comment: Changed my display name, hoping to get the answer now :)

Comment: Your delimiter is pipe. Try changing your delimiter to comma, for example.

Comment: I need the output to be a pipe delimited file only.